# Controller constructor called more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a simple controller

```
angular.module('datahubApp')
  .controller('LoginController',[ '$scope' , '$resource', LoginController]);

function LoginController($scope,$resource){
    console.log('Constructor called');
}
```

I have used the this in HTML in 2 places for two different components, in the same view

```
<div ng-controller="Logincontroller as ln"> </div>

<div ng-controller="Logincontroller as ln"> </div>
```

Now when I run the app, i see this in console

```
Constructor Called
Constructor Called
Constructor Called
```

**Question 1:**

So, this is getting called thrice. Is this normal.

**Question 2:**
In that case, how can I pass the scope variable between components?

Comment: can you show the full html? / create a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: no more code i have.. simply this is it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using same controller two times in a view. Use it one time only and it would work perfect.

You can use like:

```
<div ng-controller="Logincontroller as ln">

   <div></div> <!-- Your first div -->

   <div> </div> <!-- Your second div -->

</div>
```

AngularJS will call a controller every time it found in a view. No matter how much time is there in view part.